# jquery to highlight the selected row and column in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to highlight the complete row and column of the selected cell in a html table using jquery. I came across many examples using CSS but could not find using jquery. Please suggest.
Please find the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/70/

Below is the html code:

```
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <table border="1px">
     <tr>
               <td></td>
                    <td  bgcolor="grey">
                   <br>Column1
                    </td>


                   <td  bgcolor="grey">
                   <br>Column2
                    </td>


                   <td  bgcolor="grey">
                   <br>Column3
                    </td>


                   <td  bgcolor="grey">
                   <br>Column4
                    </td>


                   <td  bgcolor="grey">
                   <br>Column5
                    </td>
        </tr>  
   <tr>
   <td bgcolor="grey" >Row1</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data1    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

   <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data2    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data3    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data4    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data5    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

</tr>
   <tr>
   <td  bgcolor="grey">Row2</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data1    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

   <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data2    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data3    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data4    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

  <td >
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data5    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

</tr>


   <tr>
   <td  bgcolor="grey">Row3</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data1    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

   <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data2    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data3    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

  <td >
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data4    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

  <td>
     <table style="width:80%;margin:auto;border: 1px;">
     <tr>
     <td>
      Data5    </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
</td> 

</tr>
</table></td></tr></table></div>
```

--EDIT--
I cannot simplify/modify my table structure as it is generating dynamically and retrieving the values from database and display's in  cells. With my existing structure as i shown in the question / fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/70/ i need to achieve the row and column highlight.
Thanks.

Comment: So why not use CSS, where does that fail for you? (Incidentally, `bgcolor` would be best replaced though the use of CSS, now) And why is there a `<table>` element nested inside the single `<td>` of another `<table>`?

Comment: @DavidThomas , i have nested rows inside a single <td> element, to make it simple i removed it, thats the reason i have <table> inside <td>. and coming to CSS it doesn't fail but i saw lengthy code with css whereas jquery with minimal code we can acheive it.

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Tricks covered a small tutorial on how to do this with JS/jQuery here:

http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/

The best way is shown here:

```js
$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
      $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");
    }
});
```

```css
#page-wrap { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; }

table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
td, th { border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; }

.slim { width: 88px; }
.hover { background-color: #eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>test</th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have gone through the above example you mentioned , but could not understand the use of <colgroup>. and in my case i have <td> cells generating dynamically. I will get the data from database and based on the data from database it will loop and create rows and columns.@Aaron Vanston.

Comment: <colgroup> help group the columns together so the styles can be applied. Each column requires a colgroup in ordered to be targeted. on mous over of an individual cell it will find the colgroup that it belongs to and apply the hover styles.

@user222

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>    <td>Column1<td>Column2<td>Column3<td>Column4<td>Column5
  <tr><td>Row1<td>Data1  <td>Data2  <td>Data3  <td>Data4  <td>Data5
  <tr><td>Row2<td>Data1  <td>Data2  <td>Data3  <td>Data4  <td>Data5
  <tr><td>Row3<td>Data1  <td>Data2  <td>Data3  <td>Data4  <td>Data5
</table>
```

Many people close `tr`s and `td`s, but I choose not to, because those are [optional closing tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) in HTML5, and in my experience, they were never needed in HTML4.  (Google's Style Guide also recommends [omitting optional tags](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#Optional_Tags).)

All presentation styles should be done in a CSS style sheet, like this:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

tr:first-child, td:first-child {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.hovered {
  background: yellow;
}
```

With jQuery, you can add a `hover` event to the table's `td`s, which toggle the `hovered` class for the `td`'s parent row and all the `td`s in its column:

```
$('td').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent('tr').toggleClass('hovered');
  $('td:eq('+this.cellIndex+')','tr').toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

### Fiddle

---

**Edit**

Since you *can't* change your layout, the highlighting functionality is a bit more difficult.  In this case, you can use jQuery to change your multi-table layout to a single table:

```
$('table:first-child').replaceWith($('table', 'table:first-child').html());

$('table').each(function() {
  var td= $('td', this);
  if(td.length === 1) {
    $(this).replaceWith(td.html());
  }
});
```

This allows the highlighting code to work on your existing HTML.

### New Fiddle

Comment: "*Some people will tell you to close `trs` and `tds`...*" - because it looks horrible not doing so. Admittedly that's a personal preference, and yes: they're optional (as are almost all closing tags of elements that cannot be directly nested one within another of the same type). I do find it easier to avoid errors when I close elements, though.

Comment: I know I'm in the minority about optional tags, so we can agree to disagree on that point.

Comment: Sorry, as suggested above i cannot simplify/modify my table structure as it is generating dynamically and retrieving the values from database and display's in <td> cells. WIth my existing structure as i shown in the question i need to achieve the row and column highlight. @Rick Hitchcock