# Extend html table highlight row and column and make current cell a different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I found and example of highlighting a row and column on hovering with mouse.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28312853/139698

How can I make the one cell that the mouse is hovering over to a different color, but keeping the the highlighted row and column as well?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .hovered {
            background-color: teal;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts\jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>row1 col1</td>
            <td>row1 col2</td>
            <td>row1 col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 col1</td>
            <td>row2 col2</td>
            <td>row2 col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3 col1</td>
            <td>row3 col2</td>
            <td>row3 col3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('td').hover(function () {
                $(this).parent('tr').toggleClass('hovered');
                $('td:eq(' + this.cellIndex + ')', 'tr').toggleClass('hovered');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a [mre]!!

Comment: If you're generating your tr's and td's dinamically, you can try to apply and hardcode your cells classes, with separated counters for row and columns, like <td class='[tr_counter]_[td_counter]' >. Then keep your tr and td jquery rules as they are, and simply add  a rule targeting the cell's class (or id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing on the linked [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28312853/139698)

---

You can add a class to the component (`this`) itself, and apply some css for it:

```js
$(this).toggleClass('hovered-cell')
```

```css
.hovered-cell {
  background: orange;
}
```

---

```js
$('td').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hovered-cell')
  $(this).parent('tr').toggleClass('hovered');
  $('td:eq('+this.cellIndex+')','tr').toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

tr:first-child, td:first-child {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.hovered {
  background: yellow;
}

.hovered-cell {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>    <td>Column1<td>Column2<td>Column3<td>Column4<td>Column5
  <tr><td>Row1<td>Data1  <td>Data2  <td>Data3  <td>Data4  <td>Data5
  <tr><td>Row2<td>Data1  <td>Data2  <td>Data3  <td>Data4  <td>Data5
  <tr><td>Row3<td>Data1  <td>Data2  <td>Data3  <td>Data4  <td>Data5
</table>
```

---

Based on [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73788920/extend-html-table-highlight-row-and-column-and-make-current-cell-a-different-col/73788969?noredirect=1#comment130296322_73788969), here's the same idea, with a `onClick` that will keep the rows/cols colored until the next click. Just to give an idea, can be improved using eg functions to reduce duplicate code

```js
const removePersistant = () => $('.hovered-per').removeClass("hovered-per");

$('td').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hovered-cell')
    $(this).parent('tr').toggleClass('hovered');
    $('td:eq('+this.cellIndex+')','tr').toggleClass('hovered');
    $('.hovered-per').removeClass("highlight");
});

$('td').click(function() {
    removePersistant();
    $(this).toggleClass('hovered-per')
    $(this).parent('tr').toggleClass('hovered-per');
    $('td:eq('+this.cellIndex+')','tr').toggleClass('hovered-per');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

tr:first-child, td:first-child {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.hovered {
  background: yellow;
}

.hovered-cell {
  background: orange;
}

.hovered-per {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>    <td>Column1<td>Column2<td>Column3<td>Column4<td>Column5
  <tr><td>Row1<td>Data1  <td>Data2  <td>Data3  <td>Data4  <td>Data5
  <tr><td>Row2<td>Data1  <td>Data2  <td>Data3  <td>Data4  <td>Data5
  <tr><td>Row3<td>Data1  <td>Data2  <td>Data3  <td>Data4  <td>Data5
</table>
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer I'm looking for. Thank you. Would it be much harder to add: if you click on a cell to keep highlight row, column and cell permanent? But still keep hovering working too.

Comment: That's a whole different question, out of scope of your current question. I'd recommend trying youself, and if needed, ask another question with was doesn't work and what you've tried. Should be doable tho ;)

Comment: any hints :) :)

Comment: Set an extra class on the elements. Then on the next hover, remove all those classes.

Comment: I've added a new snippet m8. Hope this will get you started ;)